# Set with duplicates java - import from file - java

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, duplicates, set

I have a small project.

The project imports the txt file to String (coding similar to CSV - contains semicolons = ";").

In the next steps, the String is changed to ArrayList.

Then, using Predicate, I remove elements that do not interest me.

At the end I replace ArrayList on TreeSet to remove duplicates.
Unfortunately, there is a problem here because the duplicates occur ...

I checked in Notepadd ++ changing the encoding on ANSI to check whether there are no unnecessary characters.

Unfortunately, everything looks good and duplicates are still there.

Uploaded input file - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OqIKUTvMwK3FPzNvutLu-GYpvocUsSgu

Any idea?

```
public class OpenSCV {
    private static final String SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH = "/Downloads/all.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH);
    String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "utf-8");
    str = str.trim();
    String str2 = str.replace("\n", ";").replace("\"", "" ).replace("\n\n",";").replace("\\*www.*\\","")
            .replace("\u0000","").replace(",",";").replace(" ","").replaceAll(";{2,}",";");

        List<String> lista1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList((str2.split(";"))));

        Predicate<String> predicate = s -> !(s.contains("@"));

        Set<String> removeDuplicates = new TreeSet<>(lista1);

        removeDuplicates.removeIf(predicate);

        String fileName2 = "/Downloads/allMails.txt";
        try ( BufferedWriter bw =
                      new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter (fileName2)) )
        {
            for (String line : removeDuplicates) {
                bw.write (line + "\n");
            }
            bw.close ();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is impossible for a `Set<String>` to contain duplicate Strings. Whatever it is that you call duplicates must still be different elements (Maybe with trailing spaces, non printable characters.).

Comment: `.replaceAll(";;",";").replaceAll(";;;",";").replaceAll(";;;;",";").replaceAll(";;;;;",";");` doesn't look right. It should probably be `replaceAll(";{2,}",";")` or even avoided by using proper CVS parser.

Comment: Just a side note: don’t write `bw.close ()` inside a `try(BufferedWriter bw = …)` statement. The whole purpose of the try-with-resource statement is that you are not required to do manual closing. And you are writing *two files*. Are you looking at the right file?

Comment: Can you also include some content of your file which we could use to actually reproduce your problem? Without it we can't really help you beside *guessing* which isn't very efficient way of solving problems.

Comment: Can you explain the rationale behind your decision to use `replace` or `replaceAll`? I have the strong feeling that you don’t understand the difference between these two methods at all.

Comment: My txt file is quite big (89MB) but I created his zip file and put it on google drive - download link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OqIKUTvMwK3FPzNvutLu-GYpvocUsSgu

Comment: And you’re reading the entire 89 megabytes into a single String?  Why not read the file line by line with a BufferedReader or [Files.lines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines%28java.nio.file.Path%29)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before doing str.replace you can try str.trim to remove any spaces or unwanted and unseen characters.

```
str = str.trim()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. I added a file on which I'm working, maybe it will help